# Jquery Showing UL list structure before loading CSS ddsmoothmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am working on a private project for a client and I have integrated ddsmoothmenu. I, and the client, are experiencing the UL structure of the list showing before the styling for the menu kicks in.

Is there a way to make the menu load fully styled before so that it does not flash the UL list.. ever :)?

It doesn't do this every time. Maybe 1 out of 10 page loads.

It's on an ASP site and I don't have any javascript errors.

Please help :)

Thanks!

J

Answer (score 1):

You could either hide the list until after it has loaded, or call ddsmoothmenu quicker, rather than waiting for the DOM to finish loading.  You don't have to wait for the DOM if you know when the list exists in the DOM.  Example:

```
<ul id='menu'>
    <li>Whatever</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $('#menu').doSomethingNow();
</script>
```

Comment: Thats great, What should I put in for the .doSomethingNow?

Comment: I imagine you want replace that line with your current call to ddsmoothmenu.